# Daily Task running more times than it should

Tags: c#, windows-services

The following code runs more than once a day after it completed successfully and it should not. Why?

Note this code is running on its own thread and is not the main application's thread.

```
public bool bRunPortedNumberUpdater = false;
public bool bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday = false;

private void MainMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Parse("00:01") 
                && DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Parse("00:59") 
                && bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday == true)
            {
                bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday = false;
            }
            if (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Parse("01:00") 
                && DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Parse("03:30") 
                && bRunPortedNumberUpdater == false 
                && bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday == false)
            {
                bRunPortedNumberUpdater = true;
            }
            if (bRunPortedNumberUpdater)
            {
                WorkerMethod();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
        }
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }
}

private void WorkerMethod()
{
    while (bRunPortedNumberUpdater)
    {
        try
        {
            //do some long running job
            //when long running job complete I set values as such:
            bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday = true;
            bRunPortedNumberUpdater = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
        }
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could change `&& bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday == true` to `&& bUpdatedPortedNumbersToday` , same on the second `if`. Next, why do you check every 10 & 2 minutes if you want this run once per day? last, why don't you have comments that explain what's your logic, so people who might want to help you, might actually read your code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest better logging of the execution. When you say it runs more than once per day, what do you mean? When it runs? When it is supposed to run?

I would guess that `DateTime.Parse("01:00")` and  `DateTime.Parse("03:30")` return true when you don't expect it. Perhaps, the date time format is not right for some reason and returns true even on 13.00 and 15.30?

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

You set `bRunPortedNumberUpdater` to true only within the loop therefore the next time through the loop it causes `WorkerMethod()` to be run again.

I suspect that what you really want to do is set `bRunPortedNumberUpdater` to false after running `WorkerMethod()`